Flutter: error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to uri || Bluestacks 5
I am having a Problem with Flutter on Bluestacks 5, where every time I run my flutter app, it will print this error; "Error connecting to service protocol: HttpException: Connection was closed before complete headers were received, uri = //http://127.x.x.x/xxxxx/xxxxx", and the app will "disconnect" from the app on the emulator. The app will still run, but I can't use functions like Hot Reload.
I am using a Windows computer, and Flutter Doctor doesn't show any errors.
Do any of you have any ideas on how to solve this problem?
Please help me because I need Bluestacks 5 for debugging my flutter app, because it must be admitted that Bluestacks is very light and stable for low end pc or laptop with school/student specifications.
